# How to store auth::user profile data into Laravel view?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I work on a project to learn Laravel.

So, I create a database with users. Each user got a profile with information like: city,country,etc.

I create a table named 'profiles' where I have the following columns: id / user_id / country / city.

My routes file looks like:

```
 Route::get('editProfile', 'ProfileController@editProfileForm');
```

My ProfileController looks like:

```
public function editProfileForm() {
    return view('profile.editProfile')->with('data', Auth::user()->profile);
}
```

And when I call the view as: `{{ $data }}`in editProfile.blade, it should return the **authenticate** user data from database and also I need the row form 'profiles' table where my user_id corresponds to id form 'users' table.

The problem is that my view returns an empty string, not what I expect form the database.

Comment: where is problem?

Comment: Well when I want to display a data from profile table, I want to access it like {{$data->city}} (for an example). But my $data is empty and I don't know how to fix it.

I think I must have a connection between 'user' table and 'profiles' or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.

This is how I do it:

- In ProfileController I made the following function:

  `public function editProfileForm() {
      $userData = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('profiles', 'profiles.user_id','users.id')
        ->where('users.id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();
      return view('profile.editProfile')->with('userData', $userData);
  }`

And that's how I got my info from db in $userData var. And I can display on inputs my data like {{$userData->city}} as an example.

Thanks to all !

Answer (score 0):

Why is users and profiles two separate tables?

Comment: I make a 'profiles' table where I put stuffs like {city,country, about...etc} and I try make connection like: id from 'user' table - > 'user_id' from 'profiles' table. 

And my idea was when I access variable {{$data}} to give me the Authenticate user [id,name,email,password] + [city,country,about]. 

But want I am trying to do doesn't work...

Comment: Your'e makin it harder than it have to be.


In the model User

public function profile(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id')
}

In the model Profile

public function user(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\User')
}

In the controller

$user = User::find(1);

// from table users
echo $user->name;

// from table profile
echo $user->profile->city;

Comment: Look, in my ProfileController

I create a function index, it looks like this: 

`public function index() {

      $userData =DB::table('users')
     ->leftJoin('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', 'users.id')
     ->get();

        return view('profile.index', compact('userData'))->with('data', Auth::user()->profile);
    }`

And I have my old function editProfileForm: 

`public function editProfileForm() {
        return view('profile.editProfile')->with('data', Auth::user()->profile);
    }`


Function index query it doesn't work... or something is going wrong there...